# How to maintain object in multiple instances - C#

Tags: c#, object, byref

I am maintaining one object(Parent) in my MainWindow class. That Parent Object is being passed to another object(objMyClass). Now If I update Parent Object in mainwindow, it is not reflecting it in objMyClass object. Below is the code.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Parent objParent;
        public MyClass objMyClass;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            objParent = new Parent();
            objMyClass = new MyClass(objParent);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)checkPWB.IsChecked)
                objParent = new Child1();
            else
                objParent = new Child2();

            objParent.Display();
            objMyClass.par.Display();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public Parent par;

        public MyClass(Parent p)
        {
            par = p;
        }

    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public virtual void Display()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am Parent");
        }
    }

    public class Child1 : Parent
    {
        public override void Display()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am Child1");
        }
    }

    public class Child2 : Parent
    {
        public override void Display()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am Child2");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I am creating a new object (Child1) and assigning to my parent object which doesn't reflect it in ObjectMyClass.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the same field you can use `Func<Parent>` that would return current value of the filed:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Func<Parent> getParent = null;
    public Parent par => getParent();

    public MyClass(Func<Parent> getParent)
    {
        this.getParent = getParent;
    }
}
```

and construct your class as

```
objMyClass = new MyClass(() => objParent);
```

This way instead of having its own reference to `Parent` object that contains copy of the original value of the parameter (as in code in the question) this `MyClass` will always return current value of `objParent` field and indeed reflect changes to that field.

Alternatively you can just change `par` property directly instead of changing `objParent`.

Comment: Thank You Alexei. it solved my problem. But one question, why the object is not reflected in my code?

Comment: @virus "instead of having its own reference to Parent object that contains *copy* of the original value of the parameter (as in code in the question)". is the best I can say. I don't know how to explain that... The fact that `a = b; b = c;` does not make a == c is either obvious or very hard concept - I can't help to move from group who find it very hard to understand to one who find it obvious  :(